# Highlighting selected row of grid view inside repeater controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have a grid view inside a repeater control. when i click on a cell of grid view its open a panel inside the same repeater and page is post back. What i want is to highlight the selected row. how i can do this in asp.net?

Comment: please show some code, so we have something to work with....

Comment: I have bound the gridview row on click to a client side method but its highlights the row and when page is post back the row is not highlighted anymore the code is this.

        function toggle(obj) {
            if (obj.style.backgroundColor == '#daeef3') {

                obj.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

            } else {

                obj.style.backgroundColor = '#daeef3';
            }
        }